# Imported database function not returning a value inside route in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a REST API with Expressjs. When I started I was using only one main file with all routes, now I separated those routes, database connection and database methods in their on files.

login-db.js

```js
const { showMessage, showError } = require("../show-message-handler");
const connection = require("../db/db");

module.exports = {
  login: function (username, password) {
    let r;
    connection.query(
      "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?;", [username, password],
      (error, rows, fields) => {
        if (error)
          showError(error.code, "Couldn't retrieve user.");

        r = rows.length !== 0 ? true : false;
        showMessage(r);
      }
    );

    return r;
  }
}
```

login.js

```js
const { showMessage, showError } = require("../show-message-handler");
const router = require("express").Router();

const { login } = require("../db-methods/login-db");

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  let r = false;
  showMessage("Before login: => " + r);
  r = login(req.body.username, req.body.password);
  showMessage("After login: => " + r);

  res.send(String(r));
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I test the console print something like this:

```
// before login: false // -> r = false
// after login: undefined // -> r = undefined
// inside login function in login.js // r = true
```

So what to do to solve this? I tried with async function but isn't supported in Node v6, only in v8. I am hosting in AWS Lambda which runs v6 of Node, so I can't upgrade.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, (or not):

```
const { showMessage, showError } = require("../show-message-handler");
const connection = require("../db/db");

module.exports = {
  login: function (username, password, callback) {
    let r;
    connection.query(
      "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?;", [username, password],
      (error, rows, fields) => {
        if (error)
          showError(error.code, "Couldn't retrieve user.");

        r = rows.length !== 0 ? true : false;
        callback(null, r);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

login.js

```
const { showMessage, showError } = require("../show-message-handler");
const router = require("express").Router();

const { login } = require("../db-methods/login-db");

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  let r = false;
  showMessage("Before login: => " + r);
  login(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(error, result) {
    showMessage("After login: => " + result);
    res.send(String(result));
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

the thing is, query operation is asynchronous process, but you returned the `r` immediately, you should wait for the query to finish and use callbacks